# I want to show some values stored in database in a Joomla article

Tags: database, joomla

Hello everyone I want to show some values from the database in a joomla article in the [following manner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjlCG.png) how can I do it ???

I've created the database in the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4lSk.png) manner

Answer (score 0):

One way to include php code in your article is to use an extension like

http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sourcerer

This will allow you to put some php code that will make a query. Doing this in a Joomla way it would look like:

```
 $db = JFactory::getDbo();
 $query = $db->getQuery(true)
 $query
    ->select($db->quoteName(array('ques', 'options', 'ans')))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__yourtablename'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = ' . $idOfQuestionYouWantToGrab);
 $db->setQuery($query);
 $result = $db->loadAssoc();
```

Now you can show your question:

`<?php echo $result['ques']; ?>`

then somehow you will need to visualize questions separating them them with some regular expression, since your fields aren't structured well :/
Same with the answers. Then you will need to make some validation with JavaScript to see if answer is the correct one.